# Copy value of cell into another cell based on the value of a 3rd cell

Tags: vba, excel

I need a VBA script to copy the value of a cell (on another sheet) into a blank cell that is to the right of the original reference cell. The reference cell is a Drop Down with three values (Verbal, Written, Demonstrated). I need VBA because once the value has been entered into the cell i need to add additional comments into the cell as well.

Col G is the reference cell with a drop down. 
Col I is the destination of the VBA code

The look up range is:   Sheets.("DO NOT DELETE") Range("C2:D4")

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code for me or show me where to start site. If you have code that is not working please put it in the original post using edit and explain where it is causing the error. If not this will probably be down voted and closed as too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Make certain that your activesheet is the one with the dropdown values.  You must make a call to run this function.

```
'  This is meant to be run in a module and must be called
Sub tester()
        Dim lastRow As Long, testString As String, rng2Search As Range


            lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("G65536").End(xlUp).Row
            For i = 1 To lastRow
                If ActiveSheet.Range("G" & i) = "Verbal" Or _
                    ActiveSheet.Range("G" & i) = "Written" Or _
                    ActiveSheet.Range("G" & i) = "Demonstrated" Then
                    Set rng2Search = Sheets("DO NOT DELETE").Range("C2:C4").Find(ActiveSheet.Range("G" & i), LookIn:=xlValues)
                        If Not rng2Search Is Nothing Then
                            ActiveSheet.Range("I" & i).Value = Sheets("DO NOT DELETE").Range("D" & rng2Search.Row).Value
                        End If
                End If
            Next i
            Set rng2Search = Nothing

        End Sub
```

You can also alter this to run on your worksheet module whenever a cell in column G is changed.  Open up the worksheet module that contains your dropdown values and paste this in there.

```
'  This will run automatically if in the worksheet module    
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng2Search As Range

        If Mid(Target.Address, 1, 2) = "$G" Then
            Set rng2Search = Sheets("DO NOT DELETE").Range("C2:C4").Find(Target.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
                    If Not rng2Search Is Nothing Then
                        ActiveSheet.Range("I" & Target.Row).Value = Sheets("DO NOT DELETE").Range("D" & rng2Search.Row).Value
                    End If
        End If

    End Sub
```